# Claims identity in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, claims-based-identity

I have the following code in my controller, we are passing user id from claims identity to a peoplesoft service. I tried running this on my local but there is no claim to get the user id and it is failing.

Please let me know what would be the value of userid when its on a server and what can I pass as userid at localhost.

```
        var cp = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
        var userId = cp.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
        
        try
        {

            var soapClient = Peoplesoft.SoapClient.Create<CI_SU_MY_STUDENT_PortTypeClient, CI_SU_MY_STUDENT_PortType>("CI_SU_MY_STUDENT_G", userId);

            var results = soapClient.CI_SU_MY_STUDENT_G(new Get__CompIntfc__SU_MY_STUDENTTypeShape
            {
                OPRID = new Peoplesoft.CsMyStudent.OPRIDTypeShape3 { Value = studentId }
            });

            resultString = Utilities.XmlObjectToJsonString(results);

        }
```

Thanks

Comment: Whether you are using Asp.net Core Identity or not? After login success, have you ever added the Claim to the current user, can you share the related code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
var claims = claimsIdentity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
string userId = claims.Value;
```

Comment: claimsIdentity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier) is returning null and receiving System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' for claims.value

Comment: is the user logged in?